# Empty a text file with Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to find a way to empty a text file with Autohotkey. Unfortunetely I was unable to find any build in function that allowes you to do just that. The best solution I could come up with would be:

```
FileRead, TheText, file.txt
StringReplace, NewText, TheText, 'text to search for', 'replacement text', All
FileDelete, file.txt
FileAppend, %NewText%, file.txt
```

However, this solution won't work for me because I'm writing a tool that will add or delete content from the Windows hosts file. Deleting the hosts file is out of the question ofcourse.

So instead I'm loading the hosts file content into a variable, replace any addition made by my program with an empty string (to restore the original hosts file content) inside this variable and write it back to the hosts file. But in order to do that I need to empty the file first or it would just append the variable to the existing content.

**For those who are curious about my program:**

The program will enable/disable the automatic Skype login feature on outlook.com or hotmail.com. Ofcourse without cauing any problems for the mail functions or the Skype client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using a fileobject ([req ahk 1.1+](http://ahkscript.org/download))

just put this example in a new script file and run it to see how it works

```
/* String1
 * String2
 * String3
 * String4
 * String5
 * String6
 * String7
 * String8
 * String10
*/

msgbox % CutString(A_ScriptFullPath, "String7")

CutString(filePath, Needle)
{
    fileObj := FileOpen(filePath, "rw"), pointerPos := fileObj.Pos, RegExMatch(fileObj.read(), "O)" needle, match)

    fileObj.Seek(0), newText .= fileObj.read(match.pos-1), fileObj.Seek(match.pos + match.Len), newText .= fileObj.read()

    fileObj.Seek(pointerPos), fileObj.Write(newText), fileObj.length := StrLen(newText), fileObj.Close()
    return match.value
}
```

This function uses RegEx to find the pos and size of "needle" string in a file and then rewrites and resizes the file content without it.

You can also rewrite the function to simply cut out lines from the file.

I hope this does what your need

Comment: This seems to be a perfect solution for my situation. I'm not in the position to test it right now but I'll accept your answer as soon I've tried it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops I forgot to mark this question as answered. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about renaming it?  I've done this before.

```
hosts := "c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts"

fileread, hostsText, %hosts%
stringreplace, newText, %hostsText%, %searchtext%, %replacementtext%, all
fileappend, %hostsText%, %hosts%.bak   ;make backup
filedelete, %hosts%.temp               ;delete the temp file if it exists
fileappend, %newtext%, %hosts%.temp    ;write new text to a blank file
filemove, %hosts%.temp, %hosts%, 1     ;rename the new file to hosts - set flag to 1 to overwrite
```

Then you need to flush the DNS, no?

```
Run cmd /c ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Although this probebly works, it's not really an answer to my question. Still I think making a backup file just in case is a very good idea. Therefor I'll upvote it :) Btw I think on Windows Vista+ the hosts file takes immediate effect. No need to flush dns for it.

Comment: I've done this before in an attempt to switch between multiple hosts files.  You can have several host files and in order to switch between them you rename one to a temporary name and then just "append" to a new, blank one with the name of hosts.  It's easy and fast.  And it doesn't *lock* your hosts file.  If you enter file-reading mode, the file is locked (can't be edited) until you release it.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Run, notepad.exe invalid_response.txt
2. Sleep, 200
3. Send, ^a
4. Send, {Del}
5. Sleep, 200
6. Send, !{F4}
7. Send, {HOME}
8. Sendraw, #
9. Send, ^s
10. Sleep, 200
11. Send, !{F4}
12. Exit